# Как вывести двумерный массив в Bash?

Tags: массивы, bash

Подскажите, можно ли как-то вывести массив как двумерный таким циклом - `for i in ${array[@]}`

У меня получается вывести двумерный массив таким образом:

```
declare -A array
MSize=4

for((i=0;i<MSize;i++))
do
    for((j=0;j<MSize;j++))
    do
        let array[$i,$j]="$RANDOM % 100"
        printf "%2d " ${array[$i,$j]}
    done
    echo ""
done
```

Так получается только выводит в строку или в столбец все числа:

```
for i in ${array[@]}
do
     printf "%2d " $i
done
```

Answer (score 2):

1. программа *bash* не поддерживает многомерные массивы. только одномерные.
2. с помощью т.н. «ассоциативных массивов» (объявляются как `declare -A массив`) можно лишь **эмулировать** многомерность. например, используя символы «запятая» внутри ключей (с таким же успехом это могут быть и (почти) любые другие символы).

ключом в ассоциативных массивах служит банальная строка:

```
declare -A massiv

massiv[10]=1
massiv[0,0]=2
massiv[0,5!0]=3
massiv[wow,how]=4

for k in "${!massiv[@]}"; do
  echo "ключ    : $k"
  echo "значение: ${massiv[$k]}"
done
```

результат выполнения:

```
ключ    : wow,how                                                                                                                      
значение: 4                                                                                                                            
ключ    : 0,0                                                                                                                          
значение: 2                                                                                                                            
ключ    : 0,5!0                                                                                                                        
значение: 3                                                                                                                            
ключ    : 10                                                                                                                           
значение: 1
```

порядок сортировки ключей можно посмотреть в исходниках программы. [вот здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60398135/4827341) он изложен словами:

> Bash [associative array implementation](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/assoc.c#L77) uses a [hash library](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/hashlib.c) and stores hashes of indexes. These hashes are stored in [buckets](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/hashlib.c#L39) with 128 [default number of buckets](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/hashlib.h#L76). The hash is calculated with the function [`hash_string()`](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/hashlib.c#L145) using a simple multiplication and a bitwise XOR. The keys of the associative array are listed [in the order buckets appear](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/assoc.c#L453). [Bucket number is calculated](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/hashlib.c#L39) by a bitwise AND operation between the hash value of the key and the number of buckets decreased by 1.

поэтому, когда вы **эмулируете** двухмерный массив, на самом деле у вас получается **одномерный** массив (что вы и наблюдаете, выводя его элементы с помощью `${array[@]}`), а «строки» и «столбцы» существуют лишь в вашем воображении.

и для получения его элементов в необходимом вам порядке, да ещё и с разбивкой по воображаемым строкам/столбцам, вам надо перебирать ключи в нужном вам порядке и с нужной вам разбивкой:

```
declare -A massiv

massiv[0,1]=1
massiv[1,0]=2
massiv[0,0]=3
massiv[1,1]=4

for i in 0 1; do
  echo "«строка» номер $i"
  for j in 0 1; do
    echo "элемент из «столбца» номер $j в «строке» номер $i равен: ${massiv[$i,$j]} (ключ этого элемента — '$i,$j')"
  done
done

echo
echo "все ключи массива   : ${!massiv[@]}"
echo "все элементы массива: ${massiv[@]}"
```

результат:

```
«строка» номер 0                                                                                                                       
элемент из «столбца» номер 0 в «строке» номер 0 равен: 3 (ключ этого элемента — '0,0')                                               
элемент из «столбца» номер 1 в «строке» номер 0 равен: 1 (ключ этого элемента — '0,1')                                               
«строка» номер 1                                                                                                                       
элемент из «столбца» номер 0 в «строке» номер 1 равен: 2 (ключ этого элемента — '1,0')                                               
элемент из «столбца» номер 1 в «строке» номер 1 равен: 4 (ключ этого элемента — '1,1')                                               
                                                                                                                                       
все ключи массива   : 1,0 1,1 0,1 0,0                                                                                                  
все элементы массива: 2 4 1 3
```